# Calling an Api from button.setOnClickListener with navigation to another Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm new to Kotlin and need some guidence.

I have a Fragment and within the onCreateView i have a button, utilising setOnClickListener.

My onCreateView:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        sharedViewModel.setAppVersion(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
        sharedViewModel.setFlavor(BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
        binding.apply { viewModel = loginViewModel }
        binding.apply { paramViewModel = sharedViewModel }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         with(binding) {
             loginButton.setOnClickListener {
                 it
                 if (checkUsernamePassword()) {
                     callLoginApi(username.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
                     if (sessionKey.isNotEmpty()) {
                         Navigation.findNavController(it)
                             .navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_landingPageFragment)
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
        return view
    }
```

The button click calls an Api:

```
    private fun callLoginApi(_username: String, _password: String) {

    val login = LoginRequest(_username, _password)
    val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApiInterface::class.java)

    retrofit.sendReq(login).enqueue(
        object : retrofit2.Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                response: Response<LoginResponse>
            ) {
                if (response.body()?.sessionKey?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                    sessionKey = response.body()?.sessionKey.toString()
                    // displays a toast with session key
                    Toast.makeText(
                        activity,
                        response.body()?.sessionKey,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                    //sharedViewModel.setSessionKey(response.body()?.sessionKey.toString())
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(
                        activity,
                        response.body()?.message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
}
```

The Api call returns a Session Key, which i store but the issue i have is that when the button is clicked, the session key is returned but the button does not navigate to the next Fragment i require.  I have to click the button again, it then navigates to the Fragment but also calls the Api again and i get a new Session Key.

Anyone any ideas where i'm going wrong and what i'm missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Answer (score 0):

API call code is not synchronous, so it means that code block inside enqueue will be executed later than rest of the code in click listener code block.

You can think it like this:

1. click listener is called
2. API call is made (this execution goes to background)
3. click listener code execution is finished, skipping the if block (because sessionKey is still empty, API call is not completed yet!)
4. API call completes and sets the sessionKey

And when you click second time, the sessionKey is now not empty because API call has completed, and the navigation happens.

To solve this problem, you have to make some kind of callback to be called in retrofit2.Callback to do the navigation or call the navigation code inside retrofit2.Callback block.